# Should webgl be used for simple websites?

Tags: webgl

Should webgl be used for simple websites?

I'm not sure or it is wise to use webgl for a simple website just to give it a better look. Will this work on all devices?

Answer (score 1):

WebGL is widely supported today https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=webgl

Whether you "should" use it or not is a broad question. Remember that you aim at improving the user experience. People are forgiving when they play video games, but they don't want to hear their computer fans spin, witness their battery discharging very fast or feel their device getting hot when all they wanted was to read a cooking recipe. Try to be user friendly.

You may for instance want to cap the framerate and/or reduce the resolution on high definition devices, pause the animation loop when the window looses focus (which is not the default behaviour of requestAnimationFrame) or when there is nothing changing on the screen (if the WebGL element is interactive for example). Also, try to write efficient algorithms: it's easy to start writing things on the fragment shader or the CPU when they should be done on the vertex shader. There are many ways to accomplish the same thing and they don't put the same stress on the computer.